# How to Install “simple-spreadsheet” gem in MAC using terminal? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

How to Install “simple-spreadsheet” gem in MAC  using terminal?  (Ruby)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

With an installed Ruby (and corresponding RubyGems):

`gem install simple-spreadsheet`

If that isn't working, you should post more information about any errors you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have successfully installed it.